# Hide a fiedset HTML element with Wicket

Tags: wicket, wicket-6

I have a fieldset element in my HTML page that I want to hide under some conditions.

I usually hide labels like this.

**HTML file**

```
<label class="optional"><wicket:message key="myLabel" /></label>
```

**JAVA file**

```
Label myLabel = new Label("myLabel", new ResourceModel("my.label"));
if (true) {
   myLabel.setVisible(false);
}
```

How do I hide this?

**HTML file**

```
<fieldset class="field_set">
    <legend>
        <wicket:message key="anotherLabel"/>
    </legend>
</fieldset>
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to have a Java component for the `fieldset` too:

```
WebMarkupContainer fieldset = new WebMarkupContainer("fieldsetId");
add(fieldset);
fieldset.add(new Label("anotherLabel", ...));
...
if (condition) {
   fieldset.setVisible(false);
}


<fieldset class="field_set">
    <legend>
       <wicket:container wicket:id="anotherLabel"/>
    </legend>
</fieldset>
```

If you want the Label to control the visibility of the fieldset then instead of `WebMarkupContainer` you could use `EnclosureContainer`

```
Label label = new Label("anotherLabel", ...);
EnclosureContainer fieldset = new EnclosureContainer("fieldsetId", label);
add(fieldset);
fieldset.add(label);
...
if (condition) {
   label.setVisible(false);
}
```

Note: I've changed your usage of `<wicket:message>` with `<wicket:container>` because `wicket:message` is the no-Java version of `new Label(id, new ResourceModel(key))`. You should use one or the other. The Java version should be used when you need more control, like in your case to control the visibility.
`wicket:container` can be used when you want to Wicket to render just the textContent without any HTML element. If you don't care about having an HTML element then you can just use `<span>` instead.

Answer (score 2):

```
<wicket:enclosure>
    <fieldset class="field_set">
        <legend>
            <wicket:message key="anotherLabel"/>
        </legend>
    </fieldset>
</wicket:enclosure>
```

If the containing data value (anotherLabel) is not visible the wicket:enclosure tag will hide the rest. If you have more than one element you can pass a child attribute:  `<wicket:enclosure child="evenAnotherLabel">`

See also: https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/guide/6.x/guide/keepControl.html#keepControl_9

[edit]

Martin was a bit faster with his answer. Even though his solution looks like a bit more legwork it definitely has its advantages if you do something more sophisticated than just displaying a label. You should read the JavaDoc to EnclosureContainer to understand the difference: https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/8.x/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/basic/EnclosureContainer.html

Comment: Actually I avoid using `<wicket:enclosire>` because it has many bugs which at this point are really hard to solve. But it works fine 80% of the time.